# Code fails to find the maximum sum

Tags: c

[Link to CodeChef problem MAXSC](https://www.codechef.com/JAN18/problems/MAXSC)

Attempted solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long int n, t, k, i, j, max[701], a[701][701], sum, flag;

    scanf( "%lld", &t );

    for( k = 0 ; k < t ; k++ )
    { 
        scanf( "%lld", &n );

        for( i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++ )
        {  
            for( j = 1 ; j <= n ; j++ )
            { 
                scanf( "%lld", &a[i][j] );
                if( j == 1)
                    max[i] = a[i][1];
                if( a[i][j] > max[i] )
                    max[i] = a[i][j];
            }
        }

        sum = 0, flag = 0;

        for( i = 1 ; i <= n-1 ; i++ )
        { 
            if( max[i] &lt; max[i+1])
                sum = sum + max[i];
            else
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag == 1)
            printf("-1\n");
        else
        {
            sum = sum + max[n-1];
            printf("%lld\n", sum );
        }
    }
}
```

Compute the maximum possible value of E1 + E2 + ... + EN. If it's impossible to pick the elements E1, E2, ..., EN, print -1 instead.

Constraint:
Code should pick N elements, one from each sequence; let's denote the element picked from sequence A<sub>i</sub> by E<sub>i</sub>. For each i (2 ≤ i ≤ N), E<sub>i</sub> should be strictly greater than E<sub>i-1</sub>.

Does this constraint mean we have to choose max element from each line?

If you look at example given:

Example Input:

```
1
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output:

```
18
```

**Explanation**

Example case 1: To maximize the score, pick 3 from the first row, 6 from the second row and 9 from the third row. The resulting sum is E1+E2+E3 = 3+6+9 = 18.

If you notice they have mentioned "maximize".

Though my code finds the max, it isn't being accepted.

Comment: Titles are meant to name the problem or issue, not to ask for help. You can ask for help in the question body.

Comment: Allocating a `long long` 701x701 array locally is a call for trouble.

Comment: _Is not being accepted_ for what? Is there really no error? Does it work when you run it locally?

Comment: I imagine by 'automatic grading system'

Comment: Review `if( max[i] &lt; max[i+1])`  Invalid code.  Hmmm,  what editor are you using?

Comment: Note that in C arrays are indexed from 0. But in `scanf( "%lld", &n );` why use `long long` when `n` is used to index an array length 701?

Comment: @EugeneSh No, that's 4MB, a piece of cake on today's stacks.

Comment: Not testing the return value of scanf() is **always a bug**.

Comment: @Jens Online judges might (and will) limit the stacks below the "todays" level.

Comment: @Jens true, but in a CodeChef problem there is nothing that can be done about bad input - you can only assume it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

> why is this code not being accepted?

Code's logic is flawed.  When `max[i] < max[i+1]` is false, it sets `flag = 1;` instead of considering other elements from `a[i]`.

> Does this constraint mean we have to choose max element from each line?

No. The goal is a maximal sum, not a sum of maximums.

```
// if( max[i] &lt; max[i+1])
if(max[i] < max[i+1])
  sum = sum + max[i];
else {
  flag = 1;
  break;
}
```

The solution lies in tying other elements.  Even if that fails, perhaps a prior selection should be changed. Recursion may be employed or other analysis.  I think it would make sense to first sort each row of data to avoid this code taking `n*n` run-time.  It should be trivial to code a `n*n` solution (trying every combination).

As this is homework, leave to OP to develop the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1

3

6  10  12

4  5  7

8 9 10

-1

but output should be 6+7+10=23.

question is given  Ei should be strictly greater than Ei-1

Comment: 1
3

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9 output is 3+6+9=18 means 3<6 and 6<9 which satisfy the above problem

3

6 10 12

4 5 7

8 9 10 output is 6+7+10=23 means 12<7 which is false and 6<7 which is true and 7<10 also true so sum=23.

3

8 9 10

11 12 13

10 5 9 output is -1 because 10<13 is true but 13 is not less than 10 or 5 or 9 which is false hence output is -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
1
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output is 3+6+9=18 means 3<6 and 6<9 which satisfy the above problem

```
3
6 10 12
4 5 7
8 9 10
```

Output is 6+7+10=23 means 12<7 which is false and 6<7 which is true and 7<10 also true so sum=23.

```
3
8 9 10
11 12 13
10 5 9
```

Output is -1 because 10<13 is true but 13 is not less than 10 or 5 or 9 which is false hence output is -1.